# How can I use sepBy with an ending character in attoparsec?

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I'm trying to parse the following line:

```
ItemCount count@Int: You have purchased #{showInt count} #{plural count "item" "items"}
```

Essentially I'm trying to get:

```
  Message {
      key = "ItemCount",
      value = "You have purchased #{showInt count} #{plural count \"item\" \"items\"}.",
      parameters = [Parameter {name = "count", paramType = "Int"}]
      }
```

The first bit `ItemCount count@Int:` could be:

`ItemCount:`

or

`ItemCount count@Int count2@Int:`

So the *parameter*s could be zero or more occurrances. I'm not sure how to detect the `:` when using `sepBy`. If I were using Parsec I would look to use `sepEndBy` https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:sepEndBy.

I'm sort of looking for `sepBy` untill it sees a char of `:`. I suppose I could first consume everything untill `:` and then run an 'inner' `parse` onn that consumed string, however it seems tedious to handle all the failure cases (Partial etc), and I'm thinking there must be a better way.

Here is my code:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Attoparsec.Text
import Data.Text (Text)

data Parameter = Parameter { name :: Text, paramType :: Text } deriving (Eq, Show)
data Message = Message { key :: Text, value :: Text, parameters :: [Parameter] } deriving (Eq, Show)
data KeyAndParameters = KeyAndParameters Text [Parameter]

parseParameter :: Parser Parameter
parseParameter = do
  n <- takeWhile1 (notInClass "@")
  _ <- char '@'
  t <- takeWhile1 (const True)
  return $ Parameter { name = n, paramType = t }

parseKeyAndParameters :: Parser KeyAndParameters
parseKeyAndParameters = do
  keyV <- takeWhile1 (notInClass " :")
  params <- parseParameter `sepBy` (char ' ')
  return $ KeyAndParameters keyV params
```

Comment: Can parameter types include a `:`? Can parameter names start with a `:`? If no to both, write your parameter parser in a way that expresses those facts and `sepBy` should Just Work. (This is how I would do it in Parsec, too.)

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have solved it. I had to replace `t <- takeWhile1 (const True)` with `t <- takeWhile1 (notInClass ":")`. I'm not too sure why I expected that to produce an error. I don't actually know why it works but it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a better understanding as to how `sepBy` operates. Essentially you don't have to take the 'remaining' text into consideration, as with attoparsec you don't have to consume all the output until the end (unlike Parsec).

For example given `1+2+3=6` as input and the following:

```
parseExample :: Parser ([Text], Text)
parseExample = do
  numbers <- takeWhile1 (notInClass "=+") `sepBy` char '+'
  skip (== '=')
  total <- takeWhile1 (const True)
  return $ (numbers, total)
```

Will return: `( [ "1" , "2" , "3" ] , "6")`

After the `skip (== '=')` you are free to parse the remaining input in whichever way you choose.